# Javascript's innerHtml is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a function that replaces the h1 html once clicked on. It somehow doesn't seem to work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my Javascript:

```
  function changeToYoMaMa(el) {    
    el.innerHtml = "<h1>" + "Yo Mama" + "</h1>";
  };

  var el = document.getElementById("heading");

  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      changeToYoMaMa(el);
  });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript tests</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="heading">hello world</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripttests.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `innerHTML`

Comment: @karthick There won't be any errors.

Comment: @BenM. Oh yes it will be undefined.

Comment: @karthick No, it won't. The code given will assign a property of `innerHtml` to `el`, which is perfectly valid. So after running the function, logging the `innerHtml` property of the element will show `Yo Mama`.

Answer (score 1):

JS is case-sensitive. It should be `innerHTML`, and furthermore `innerHTML` sets the content of the element, thus there's no need to wrap the `Yo Mama` inside another `<h1>` tag within your function:

```js
function changeToYoMaMa(el) {    
    el.innerHTML = 'Yo Mama';
};

var el = document.getElementById("heading");

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeToYoMaMa(this);
});
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use innerHTML instead of innerHtml.

This is case-sensitive

```
el.innerHTML = "<h1>" + "Yo Mama" + "</h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeToYoMaMa(el) {    
    el.innerHTML = "<h1>" + "Yo Mama" + "</h1>";
  };

  var el = document.getElementById("heading");

  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      changeToYoMaMa(el);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript tests</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="heading">hello world</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripttests.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript is case sensitive. Please correct 'el.innerHtml' to 'el.innerHTML'

Comment: Why do you add an answer, if there already exist 2 other answers with exactly the same content? Upvote them instead. Also, you should not include the `h1` markup...